# lwc component for stopwatch does not work if the tab is not active

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a lwc component for stopwatch.(using in utility bar)
when the tab is active the stopwatch runs fine but when i move to other tab the stopwatch does not work properly (show false time)

this is my javascript code for the timer

.js

```
        var parentThis = this;

        // Run timer code in every 1000 milliseconds
        this.timeIntervalInstance = setInterval(function() {

            // Time calculations for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds
            var hours = parentThis.zeroPadding(Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)), 2);
            var minutes = parentThis.zeroPadding(Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)), 2);
            var seconds = parentThis.zeroPadding(Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000 * 60)) / 1000), 2);
            // var milliseconds = parentThis.zeroPadding(Math.floor((parentThis.totalMilliseconds % (1000))), 3);
            
            // Output the result in the timeVal variable
            parentThis.timeVal = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;   
            
            parentThis.totalMilliseconds += 1000;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

what can be done so that timer runs properly even if the tab is not active?

[image: user should ba able to see time ticking here]

Comment: instead of using totalMilliseconds just capture a Date() and then in your interval show difference between that Date() and a new Date(); also make use of `connectedCallback()` to refresh that value and `disconnectedCallback()` to stop your interval

Comment: I though of that but user must be able to see time ticking each second if he is in the active window.
which it does not but not working if not in active window

Comment: i am really lost. If it is not an active window, how is your component still displayed?

Comment: sorry not window its a tab of a browser.
if i switched the tab the time is messed up

Comment: That's because you are measuring 'active elapsed' time. You need to just measure time between a start point and `now`. That way there are no ticks recorded.

Comment: yes but need to shows the ticks as per requirement of the user. The clock must be ticking